# Aumentando a capacidade de um int - C

Tags: c, alocação, falha-de-segmentação

Ao tentar calcular qual o maior primo que pode fazer uma divisão de resto 0 com o número 600851475143, recebo o erro segmentation fault com o seguinte script:

```
int count_1 = 0, count_2 = 0, soma = 0, maior = 0;
  int numero_maximo[600851475144];

  for (count_1 = 2; count_1 <= 600851475143; count_1++)
  {
    numero_maximo[count_1] = count_1;
  }

  for (count_1 = 2; count_1 <= 600851475143; count_1++)
  {
    if (numero_maximo[count_1] == count_1)
    {
      if (600851475143 % count_1 == 0)
      {

        if (count_1 > maior)
        {
          maior = 0;
          maior = count_1;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Embora tenha usado long long e usigned para aumentar a capacidade do int, ainda sim o erro persiste, já que int não suporta o valor que preciso passar. Tentei a utilização de alocação dinâmica mas não fui muito feliz.

Comment: O valor máximo que você consegue armazenar em um long long é 9223372036854775807 que é bem maior que o seu 600851475143. Seu erro é outro, reveja suas declarações de variáveis, mas note que está fazendo coisas sem sentido como este array com a sequencia de números inteiros de 0 até 600851475143.

Comment: @anonimo, consegue apontar o que há de errado?

Comment: Se você quer calcular o maior primo menor ou igual a 600851475143 não seria mais sensato começar dele e ir pegando os anteriores até achar um primo do que começar de 2 e ir calculando até achar o máximo? Além disso seu cálculo de primalidade  está errado.

Comment: @anonimo sua primeiro observação para pertinente. Quanto a segunda, usei o crivo de eratóstenes com uma modificação útil, não vejo como pode estar errado, mas agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Como usou o Crivo de Eratóstenes  se você armazena *todos* os inteiros de 0 até 600851475144 e não apenas os primos já calculados do intervalo?